# jasmine unit testing was method called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a simple unit test I am trying to write. I simply need to test if my function was called. In my service I have a simple method that calls another method like so

```
svc.getNewestNotifications = function getNewestNotifications() {
    getNewNotifications(username);
};
```

in my test:

```
describe('notification service tests', function () {
    var $rootScope, $http, $q, notificationSvc, $httpBackend;
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_,_$http_,_$httpBackend_,_$q_,_$sce_,_notificationsFeedService_){
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $http = _$http_;
    $q = _$q_;
    notificationSvc = _notificationsFeedService_;
    _scope_ = $rootScope.$new();
    $scope = _scope_;

    $httpBackend.whenGET(/\.html$/).respond('');

}));

describe("getNewestNotifications test", function() {
        it('calls the getNewestNotifications when scroll to top', function() { 
            spyOn(notificationSvc, 'getNewestNotifications').and.callThrough();
            expect(notificationSvc.getNewestNotifications).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });   

}
```

Its the " describe("getNewestNotifications test", function() {} " block that is my issue. I get "Expected spy getNewestNotifications to have been called." in the console. I am very new to unit testing in general and I am at a complete loss as to why I am seeing this i am simply trying to test that the method was indeed called. Any help?

Comment: I ome `svc.getNewestNotifications` this method getting called

Comment: @PankajParkar I dont understand your comment

Comment: In `it` section you should call something, now you have only expectation. Why `notificationSvc.getNewestNotifications` should be called - by what?

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski that is a really good question. I guess that is why I am so confused. None of this makes any sense to me what so ever. I have no idea how any of this could possibly work. Javascript makes sense but this Unit testing stuff I am totally lost. I guess i figured the test would know that the service should call the method. I dont know. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to assert that `getNewNotifications` is called whenever `svc.getNewestNotifications` is called.

To test this effectively, you'll need to define `getNewNotifications` as a method of the `svc` object so that it's available in your test:

```
svc.getNewNotifications = function getNewNotifications(user) {
  // method definition
};
```

You should update the call to `svc.getNewestNOtifications`:

```
svc.getNewestNotifications = function getNewestNotifications() {
    svc.getNewNotifications(username);
};
```

In your test, you create a spy for the `getNewNotifications` method. You then call the `getNewestNotifications` method and assert that `getNewNotifications` was called:

```
describe("getNewestNotifications test", function() {
  it('calls the getNewestNotifications when scroll to top', function() {
    // set a spy on the 'getNewNotifications' method
    spyOn(notificationSvc, 'getNewNotifications').and.callThrough();
    // call the 'getNewestNotifications'. If the function works as it should, 'getNewNotifications' should have been called.
    notificationSvc.getNewestNotifications();
    // assert that 'getNewNotifications' was called.
    expect(notificationSvc.getNewNotifications).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: I like your thinking however getNewNotifications() is a private function declared like:    ` function getNewNotifications() { // do stuff } ` so how do I do this if this is the case?